# Violación de segmento al comprobar el tamaño de una std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con `std::initializer_list`. La idea es usarlo en lugar del clásico *{puntero-al-primero, tamaño}*.

La prueba es simple: una lista de elementos de menú, generarlo, y comprobar la entrada del usuario.

Para esto último, uso una `std::string` y llamadas a `getline( )`.

Por algún motivo que se me escapa, si **después de obtener la entrada del usuario** llamo a `size( )`, el programa muere inesperadamente:

```
std::string userInput;

do {
  getline( cin, userInput );

  if( cin.eof( ) || cin.bad( ) ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Error al leer de std::cin !\n" ); }
  if( userInput.empty( ) ) { printEntries( menu ); continue; }
  if( userInput.size( ) != 2 ) { continue; }
  ^^ AQUÍ MUERE
  ...
```

Sin embargo, si comento el último `if( )` (el que comprueba que el tamaño sea `!= 2`), el código funciona correctamente.

¿ Como es posible esto, si justo en la línea anterior compruebo que `userInput` no esté vacío ?

Si intento reproducir el problema con un código mínimo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( ) {
  std::string userInput;

  std::getline( std::cin, userInput );

  if( std::cin.eof( ) || std::cin.bad( ) ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Error al leer de std::cin !\n" ); }
  if( userInput.empty( ) ) { std::cout << "Mostrar menu otra vez\n"; }
  if( userInput.size( ) != 2 ) { std::cout << "Entrada incorrecta\n"; }

  return 0;
}
```

El error **no se reproduce**.

Con el depurador, en el código problemático y justo antes de la llamada, observo que el contenido de `userInput` es corecto: contiene siempre lo último leído de `std::cin`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no se me ocurre el porqué de este comportamiento.

El código completo:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct MenuEntry {
  char key;
  const char *label;
  void ( *action )( );
};

using MenuList = std::initializer_list< MenuEntry >;

static void doExit( ) {
  std::cout << "\nFin del programa.\n";
  ::exit( 0 );
}

const MenuList MainMenuEntries = {
  { '0', "Salir", doExit }
};

static const MenuEntry *manageMenu( MenuList menu ) {
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin;

  auto printEntries = []( MenuList menu ) {
    for( const auto &item : menu ) {
      cout << "  " << item.key << ". " << item.label << '\n';
    }
  };

  printEntries( menu );

  std::string userInput;
  const MenuEntry *select;

  do {
    getline( cin, userInput );

    if( cin.eof( ) || cin.bad( ) ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Error al leer de std::cin !\n" ); }
    if( userInput.empty( ) ) { printEntries( menu ); continue; }
    if( userInput.size( ) != 2 ) { continue; }

    select = std::find_if( menu.begin( ), menu.end( ), [&userInput]( const MenuEntry &me ){
      return userInput[0] == me.key;
    } );
  } while( select == menu.end( ) );

  return select;
}

int main( ) {
  while( true ) {
    const MenuEntry *userAction = manageMenu( MainMenuEntries );
    std::cout << "Elegido " << userAction->label;
    userAction->action( );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compila perfectamente con `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -ggdb -g3 -o test test.cpp`, sin *warnings* ni errores.

Versión del g++: `g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10.1) 8.3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con std::initializer_list. La idea es usarlo en lugar del clásico {puntero-al-primero, tamaño}.

Para eso existen los contenedores de la stl, como por ejemplo `std::vector`. La utilidad de `std::initializer_list` es permitir la inicialización de objetos *al vuelo*, de hecho la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) deja muy claro lo limitado de su uso:

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

Que más o menos viene a decir:

> No está garantizada la existencia del array subyacente una vez la lista de inicialización original deje de existir. El almacenamiento de `std::initializer_list` no está especificado ( podría ser automático, temporal, estático en memoria de solo lectura,  depende de la situación)

Es decir, estos objetos, principalmente, de usar y tirar. Son temporales y no es conveniente usarlos para otros menesteres.

**Pero ¿Y dónde dices que puede estar el problema?**

Yo apostaría a que el problema se encuentra en esta línea:

```
const MenuEntry *userAction = manageMenu( MainMenuEntries );
```

Ya que si miramos la declaración de `manageMenu` vemos que se está haciendo una copia de `MenuList`, que es la lista de inicialización:

```
static const MenuEntry *manageMenu( MenuList menu ) {
//                                           ~~~~ Parámetro por copia
```

Reemplazar `std::initializer_list` por `std::vector`, por ejemplo, no requiere demasiados cambios:

```
using MenuList = std::vector< MenuEntry >;

static const MenuEntry *manageMenu( MenuList menu ) {

  // ...

  MenuList::const_iterator select;

  return &(*select);
}
```

Comment: Pues si, al final era eso. Un resultado curioso, sin duda ... de ahí lo de `comportamiento indefinido`, supongo :-)